# Find difference in second field, report using first field (awk)

Tags: shell, awk, difference

I have 2 (dummy) files

**file1.txt**

```
Tom 25
John 27
Bob 22
Justin 37
Nick 19
Max 42
```

**file2.txt**

```
Tom 25
John 40
Bob 22
Justin 37
Nick 19
Max 24
```

I want to compare the Second field of these files (the numbers). Then If they are different, report using the First field (Names). So the expected output would be the following.

```
John's age in file1.txt is different from file2.txt
Max's age in file1.txt is different from file2.txt
```

I don't know if my approach is good but I first parse the ages into another file and compare them. If they are different, I will look in which line number is the difference. Then I will go back to the original file and parse the Name of the person from THAT line.

I run the following code in **shell**.

```sh
$  awk '{print $2}' file1.txt > tmp1.txt
$  awk '{print $2}' file2.txt > tmp2.txt
$
$  different=$(diff tmp1.txt tmp2.txt | awk '{$1=""; print $0')
$
$  if ["${different}"]; then
$     #This is to get the line number where the ages are different
$     #so that I can go to THAT line in file1.txt and get the first field.
$     awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}!($0 in a){print FNR}' tmp1.txt tmp2.txt > lineNumber.txt
$  fi
```

However, I am blocked here. I don't know if my approach is right or there's an easier approach.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '
    NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}
    a[$1] != $2 {print $1"\047s age in "ARGV[1]" is different from "ARGV[2]}
' file1.txt file2.txt
```

Comment: Why store `$0` in `a` and then split it later to get `$2` instead of only storing `$2` in `a`? You could also use `ARGV[]` in the print or save/use `FILENAME` instead of hard-coding file names.

Answer (score 4):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next} $2!=a[$1]{print "Age of "$1" is different"}' file1 file2
```

Comment: You don't want to be doing a regular expression comparison on the fields, you just want `!=`.

Comment: @sudo_O thanks for your comment. updated the ans. i thought regex won't hurt.

Answer (score 1):

If both files list the same names, something like this works:

```
join file{1,2}.txt | awk '$2 != $3 { print "Age of " $1 " is different" }'
```

Comment: Join requires the input to be sorted first.

Comment: @sudo_O GNU join at least seem to relax that requirement if all lines can be paired, and operates flawlessly with the files given by the original poster.